# jQuery function improvement

Tags: jquery, function, jquery-validate

How could I improve next function?

```
function treatFormLinks () {
    if (!$('#One input').valid() ) {
        $('#LinkOne').addClass('hasErrors');    
    }
    if (!$('#Two input').valid() ) {
        $('#LinkTwo').addClass('hasErrors');    
    }
    if (!$('#Three input').valid() ) {
        $('#LinkThree').addClass('hasErrors');  
    }
};

$("#Submit").click(function () {
    treatFormLinks();
});
```

For example, if I'd had hundred (`#One`, `#Two` .etc) containers it would be stupid to create conditions for each case. So how could I make it less "id selector dependent".

Thank you!

Comment: Give the elements a common class name instead of an `id` and use an `each` loop. You'll need to post some markup to get a fully-working answer though.

Comment: I bet the folks at [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/?as=1) would have several good ideas...

Comment: Without knowing the structure of your markup, its hard to tell. How does `#LinkThree` relate to `#Three`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using `each` and `toggleClass` methods.

```
function treatFormLinks () {
   $('#One, #Two, #Three').each(function(){
      $('#Link'+this.id).toggleClass('hasErrors', !$('input', this).valid())
   })
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Put the inputs, and links in jQuery objects, so that related elements have the same index. Then:

```
$inputs.each(function ( i ) {
    $links.eq( i ).toggleClass( 'hasErrors', $( this ).valid() );
});
```